# Can I use a Retail DVD media with an OEM key to install Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, license, oem

I got a Fujitsu computer with OEM license key and Windows Vista. I would like to reinstall Windows on it. But I didn't get any Windows media with it. However, I do poses more than just one DVD installation disc from my Retail copies of Windows Vista that I use on other computers. Can I use this media instead? Or do I have to order a specialty OEM DVD media from the manufacturer or Microsoft?

**Update:** I have found some partition called "EISA" configuration partition. It is a hidden partition that I found in Disk Management. How can I make use of this? Do I boot from it or do I mount it to a drive letter and access it inside Windows? Can this be used to restore the computer? It is about 11 GB in size.

Comment: You should be able to go back to the OEM and get a copy of Windows throught the OEM provider.

Comment: OEM is FSC - Fujitsu Siemens Computers - and they are out of business. It was a joint venture between Fujitsu and Siemens, founded in 1999 and defunct as of 1 April 2009. You think Fujitsu could still provide the required OEM disc? Also, will any Fujitsu Siemens OEM disc do or does it have to be customized specifically for this model?

Answer (score 2):

Did you get the key off the COA sticker? I have used the following methods more than once on other people's laptops and managed to activate Vista every single time:

1. Do **not** enter the key during Setup! Wait till Setup's complete and you're in Windows, then go to System and change your product key there (or run the Activation Wizard using `slui`)
2. Use phone-based activation

---

As for your recovery partition (if it is indeed one), try pressing each function key (**F9** etc.) in turn as the computer's booting up, and see if you're able to spot a system recovery option.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

you have to download a OEM iso (it's legal if you have your own license)

or better solution: if your pc has a recovery partition use that to "reinstall" windows

Comment: I have found some partition called "EISA" configuration partition. It is a hidden partition that I found in Disk Management. Is that the one?

Comment: yes! that's the recovery partition.. it's (usually) 8-16 gb.. reboot the pc, press F12 (usually F12, but it can change!) when fujitsu logo appears and select "recovery and utility"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of OEM key that is used. If it is a true OEM key, then yes you will need to get a copy of OEM windows in order to be able to activate it. Typical retail windows will not accept this code.

However, sometimes they will use an OA key. I'm not sure what it stands for, but you can reuse it on a retail install. We do this at my work by buying OA machines, installing our Sysprepped images that contain all of the software pre-installed, then activate the computer using the key it came supplied with.

Comment: How do I tell if it is an OA key?...

Comment: It will state it on the sticker

Answer (score 0):

Just today I installed a "Vista multiedition x64 with sp2 english" ISO I got off the internet from getmyos.com on OEM HP desktop. The PC I had was an old hp which had Vista home basic. I had forgotten all passwords and did a clean install using that iso. Initially I typed the key in the setup and later after the installed vista was running for the first time I got an invalid key message.

But when I tried activate by phone, and called the number, I had to type in a long installation ID generated after having clicked next and then received a long code in return from the automated voice. After that, clicking next and I get a genuine activation complete.

I had no idea what just happened. I had wiped all the stuff on the drive for this random ISO install and I think maybe the PC stored and passed oem info when the activation is done using the phone activation method. This was done in India btw. Maybe other countries have different rules about OEM phone activation

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification

An `OEM` install is a **PRE**install -- An `OEM` has purchased a **VOLUME** license to `PRE`install copies on their computers.

You do NOT require a KEY to use it.

**YES** you *can* install (upgrade) with your chosen version **providing** the install/upgrade *sees* the previous version installed on your computer.

Anything else is (at best) a shot in the dark.